# Convert Blackberry web works app to blackberry java app

Tags: cordova, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-webworks

I have created a BlackBerry app using phone-gap web works framework, but that framework only supports BlackBerry OS 5 or higher. I want to convert my app to use BlackBerry java, so it can run on earlier BlackBerry OS versions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a trivial task. You will need to rewrite the application on java to support older RIM OS versions.

WebWorks/PhoneGap applications are runing implicitly in [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) class instance that is available only in RIM OS 5 and newer OS-es.

Old RIM API has old BrowserField implementation. But it is not capable to run WebWorks/PhoneGap apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *Absolutely* need to support versions of BlackBerry OS older than 5.0, I'd highly recommend you simply don't.  Focus your efforts on the newer platforms with stronger support for web standards and developer APIs.

Here is the breakdown of App World usage by OS. OS 4.x is only 2% of all paid downloads and 6% of all free downloads:

https://developer.blackberry.com/appworld